# Multisite admin on completely different Codeigniter install.. Duplicate content?

Tags: codeigniter, admin, code-duplication

I am using codeigniter for three of my websites. I use a seperate install for each as I am under the belief that as they grow they will each need there own server, and this setup just seems easier.

I am developing the adming backend for these three sites, and decided the best way to do this would be a fourth CI install on a completely different server/domain for security.

This way each morning I can login, see all the stats and admin tasks required for all of my sites, and I can conduct them from one place.

The problem with this is a requirement for duplicate code.. code from the models of each of my sites needs to in part be duplicated in the admin site.

Less than ideal, but does this really matter? Is there a better way around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter 2.* allows third-party packages, that can be anywhere on the server. If you have all your sites on different servers it could be a problem, but if you have them on one, you can use the to have shared code. Third-party packages are similar to modules, but do not have any routing.

For further information refer to [this topic](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/04/codeigniter-packages-modules) by Phil Sturgeon and to [CodeIgniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. in my understanding, if u are going 3 different websites on 3 different servers, it is anyways going to have you manage duplicate code (if required) on 3 different servers. But if all are going to be on same server, then u can create HMVC architecture like spark where u can centralize all the duplicating code and then use it as and where required. This way you will be saved of the duplicate coding.

Other way around was something a crud and not tested solution, that you say its only the 4th application where u need to have the code from all other 3 applications, then u can create softlinks to the codes and try. May be that can help u solve your problem.